# More efficient way to find word (and its letters' indexes) diagonally in Array (or list of lists)

Tags: python, matrix, crossword

I'm looking for one fast method to find words in Array and get them letters' indexes.
Words can be put horizontally, Vertically, Diagonally, in each direction (left-right, right-left, top-bottom, bottom-top, bottomleft-topright, topright-bottomleft, bottomright-topleft, topleft-bottomright).
Major problem is Diagonally dimension... How can I do?

Example:

```
Matrix:
   [['CHYD'],
    ['IAOB'],
    ['LGTA'],
    ['EFGE'],
    ['RXBW']]

Words:
   ['CAT',
    'DOG',
    'EGO',
    'RELIC',
    'TOY']
```

I need to obtain a dictionary with keys=Rowindex and Value=[set of column indexes of found words' letters].
In my Example, I'll find:

- 'CAT' in (0,0), (1,1), (2,2)
- 'DOG' in (0,3), (1,2), (2,1)
- 'EGO' in (1,2), (2,1), (3,0)
- 'RELIC' in (0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (4,0)
- 'TOY' in (0,2), (1,2), (2,2)
- 'TAC' in (0,0), (1,1), (2,2)

I would my final output is Found_Word={0:[0,2,3], 1:[0,1,2], 2:[0,1,2], 3:[0], 4:[0]}

Can you help me? I hope I was clear :)

P.s. I can use all Basic Python libraries (included in Anaconda Distribution), like numpy, colleciotions, itemtools and similar.
I can't use Global Variables or classes.

Comment: I guess could define your initial matrix in such a way that you don't need to worry about processing diagonals  and verticals. Eg you would 5th element `[CILER]` and a 6th `[HAGFX]` and so on.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is this homework? The reason you should be upfront if it is or is not an assignment is because you will get better answers if the volunteers here know the goal behind the task.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+word+search+puzzle) are some of the problems that are word puzzle solutions. I looked at a C++ solution that I had to do for school and it was longer than some of the python solutions in the link I provided.

Comment: Yeah @PauloScardine, This is an Homework, but the task is more extended.
I have to start from txt file: It has some \n at beginning, the crossword (letters are divided from \t and rows are divided from \n), some \n in the middle, the words I have to search divided from \n and, finally, some \n in the end.
I have to join all letters that remain from words removal... I thought to arrive to "Found_Word" dictonary, so I can remove from each row (with index Found_Word.keys()) the letters with index in Found_Word.value().
Then I can join all letters remained and I'll have the solution.

Comment: I thought I would add another suggestion. Once you have built the letters' matrix, you might want to surround the matrix with a character that won't occur in the words. My teacher made this suggestion and it makes the solution simpler (by telling you when you've run off the grid while searching for a word.